# Crossbow feat with leg-strap to fire multiple times

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, ranger

If I (Monster Slayer Ranger) take the crossbow feat at lvl 4, is it possible to shoot more than two crossbow bolts in a turn. I'm envisioning at lvl 5 when I get an extra attack. I would think I could hire a blacksmith to make a leg-strap crossbow loader?

Would I be able to take 3 shots in a turn? (2 attack, 1 bonus attack)

Comment: Hi Dantos, welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] to find out how things work here, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: What type of crossbow are you imagining being leg-strapped? Hand/Light/Heavy? While we're at it, I'm not sure what your leg-strap does: is it to help with loading, or is it holding another (pre-loaded) crossbow, or is it a hard mount leaving both hands free otherwise? I just can't visualize what you're describing.

Comment: By "Crossbow feat" I assume you mean Crossbow Expert feat. I think you should clarify that if you are and note referring to some homebrew material.

Answer (score 11):

### You only need 1 hand crossbow (and it must be in your hand)

I assume you are referring to the the [Crossbow Expert](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/crossbow-expert) feat (since this is the only published feat that mentions crossbows). If you take this feat at level 4 and then gain Extra Attack at level 5, **you can load and fire the *same* hand crossbow 3 times per turn**: twice with your attack action and Extra Attack, and a third time with your bonus action using the Crossbow Expert feat. This is possible because the feat allows you to ignore the loading property, which would otherwise prevent you from using your Extra Attack with it.

In fact, I believe the *only* way to get the full 3 attacks per turn is to be holding exactly one hand crossbow in your hand. If you were holding 2 hand crossbows, the [ammunition property](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties) would prevent you from reloading them after you fire them, because

> you need a free hand to load a one-handed weapon

And if you could somehow wield a hand crossbow with your leg, it would no longer be considered a "one-handed" weapon, which would prevent you from using the bonus attack from Crossbow Expert. And you would still need a free hand to reload it anyway. So, given all of these complications, by far the simplest way to get the full value out of the Crossbow Expert feat is to wield a single hand crossbow in one hand while keeping the other hand free in order to load it, as described above.

---

### You (probably) can't wield weapons with your legs

Certain weapons, like heavy crossbows, have the two-handed property, which says:

> This weapon requires two hands when you attack with it.

This property clearly prevents you from wielding the weapon with your leg, or even with two legs: you *need* to use two hands. For all the other weapons without the two-handed property, I can't find anything in the rules that directly says they *must* be wielded in your hands. However, although there is no explicit "one-handed" weapon property, there is strong circumstantial evidence that the designers consider all non-two-handed weapons to be one-handed weapons. First, there is the Crossbow Expert feat, and the ammunition property, which both make reference to one-handed weapons. In addition, the [rules for melee attacks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MeleeAttacks) say:

> A melee attack typically uses a handheld weapon such as a sword, a warhammer, or an axe.

Similarly, the rules for improvised weapons also reference holding the weapon in your hands:

> An improvised weapon includes any object you can wield in one or two hands, such as broken glass, a table leg, a frying pan, a wagon wheel, or a dead goblin.

Finally, the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice/sage-advice-compendium) also references one-handed weapons in a few rulings, such as:

> #### Dual Wielder
>
> **Can my character wield two heavy weapons if she has the Dual Wielder feat?** No. The Dual Wielder feat lets you wield two one-handed weapons. Every heavy weapon in the Player’s Handbook also has the two-handed property.

This ruling strongly implies that any non-two-handed weapon is considered a one-handed weapon, or else it wouldn't be eligible for two-weapon fighting. In general, although it's never explicitly stated, the intent seems to be that **having only two hands limits the number of weapons you can wield at once**, with every weapon requiring either 1 or 2 hands to wield.